# Migrating WPF to phone 8.1 with ViewPort3D

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1, viewport3d

About to embark a migration of a WPF application that uses ViewPort3D.
My 1st research shows this class is not supported on Phone 8.1. Am I correct?
And if so, what are my options for migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't anything similar to ViewPort3D in Windows Phone.  That leaves you with a couple of options:

**Use [PlaneProjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.media.planeprojection.aspx) to re-create the 3D effects**

This is very limited in what it can do relative to Viewport3D, but if your application is only using simple 3D effects, then it may suffice.

**Use [Windows Phone Direct3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207062%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**

This gives you the full set of graphics capabilities, but requires [low-level graphics programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714075%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) with C++.

Comment: I will do a proof of concept with planeprojection.